# session and session flash in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am really confused on  difference between storing in session flash and flash and what type of case we need session flash . I studied on laravel documentation but didnt get it .

I am new to laravel .Any help is truly appreciated .

Answer (score 1):

From [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/session#flash-data):

> Sometimes you may wish to store items in the session only for the next request. You may do so using the `flash` method. Data stored in the session using this method will only be available during the subsequent HTTP request, and then will be deleted.

So, if you want to store the data only for the next request, use the `flash()`method and if you want to store it for all requests, use:

```
session(['key' => 'value'])
```

Answer (score 1):

An example:
A user fills out the contact form and you want to give him a confirmation that the message has been sent correctly. So you redirect him to the landing page and store this message in the session. When the page loads, the message is displayed.

i.eg.

```
return redirect('contactform/')->with('message','Your message has been sent!');
```

Or you can set the flash message just before the redirection code:

```
$request->session()->flash('message', 'Your message has been sent!');
return redirect('contactform/');
```

You can then display the message like this:

```
@if (session('message'))
  <div class="message-has-been-sent-confirmation">
      {{ session('message') }}
  </div>
@endif
```

Now you can apply this to any case: confirmations, errors, welcome message etc.